# Assigning an integer literal to a double variable in Java

Tags: java, double, int, variable-assignment, literals

If I do the following

```
double d = 0;
```

since 0 is an integer literal, which uses 32 bits, and d is a double variable that uses 64 bits, will the remaining 32 bits be filled with random garbage, or does Java promote the literal correctly?

Comment: its very easy to check isn't it?

Comment: @yurib a couple of test runs shouldn't be depended on.  After all, the behavior, if not specified, might be implementation dependent.

Comment: The bits in `d` will correspond to the `double` representation of zero. You seem to think that the first 32 bits of `d` will be the same as the 32 bits in the `int` representation of zero though, which is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java promotes it correctly, otherwise there'd be a rather large body of code that was problematic :-)

[Section 5.1.2 of the Java language spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#25214) details this:

> The following 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:

```
byte to short, int, long, float, or double
short to int, long, float, or double
char to int, long, float, or double
int to long, float, or double
long to float or double
float to double
```

> Widening primitive conversions do not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value. Indeed, conversions widening from an integral type to another integral type and from float to double do not lose any information at all; the numeric value is preserved exactly. Conversions widening from float to double in strictfp expressions also preserve the numeric value exactly; however, such conversions that are not strictfp may lose information about the overall magnitude of the converted value.
>
> Conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, may result in loss of precision-that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode.

Converting from a 32-bit Java `int` to a `double` (which, in Java, has 50+ bits of precision), will not lose the magnitude *or* any precision. If the constant you use is forced to a `long` due to its value, you *may* lose precision, since a `long` has 64 bits of precision.

Answer (score 1):

java automatically converts double to integer.ie upcast
so memory is automatically managed by jvm.
but it can not automatically cast double to integer ie.downcast.